# ANSI Escape Sequences Disappear When Running a Ruby Script to Output to Geektool

Tags: ruby, zsh, ansi-escape, geektool

I am trying to use the OS X app [GeekTool](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/geektool/id456877552?mt=12) to print colorized text output onto my Desktop.  GeekTool allows you to place little windows called "geeklets" onto the Desktop.  One kind of Geeklet displays the output of a shell command.

My desired output should come from a text file that I am parsing with a ruby script.  I am using the ruby gem [colorize](https://github.com/fazibear/colorize) to add ANSI escape sequences around strings in Ruby.  My goal is to output these strings to Geektool and display colorized text.

When I run the Ruby script in terminal (both Terminal and iTerm2, using both zsh and bash) the output is perfectly well-colorized.  But when I run the script in GeekTool, it is not-- the escape sequences are not shown in the output, but there is no color.  I know GeekTool supports ANSI escape sequences, because when I run this shell command:

```
printf "\e[0;35;49mabcd\e[0m"
```

I get colorized GeekTool output.  `echo $SHELL` also tells me that GeekTool is using the same zsh executable I normally use.  But for some reason, my ruby script will not print colorized output.  Instead what I see is mono-color output, but with the escape sequences stripped.

My script uses Ruby's `puts` to output the strings containing the escape sequences.  I tried switching to `p`.  When run in the terminal, this yields non-colorized output with the escape sequences intact.  When run in GeekTool, I also get non-colorized output, but the escape sequences have again disappeared.

Anyone know where my escape sequences are going?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround for this problem.  I needed to drop the colorized gem and "double escape" the escape sequences.  I colored a string by wrapping it with strings like the ones below:

```
"\\e[0;36;49m"  # example color
"\\e[0m"        # clear
```

After building one large string containing many of these escape sequences, I did

```
command = "printf \"#{mystring}\n\""  # The trailing \n is needed to prevent Geektool from displaying [m at the end for some reason
exec(command)
```

This did the trick.  It seems that the strings were being processed twice somehow in outputting to Geektool.  The double backslash in front of the escapes `\\e` is needed to keep them from being consumed on the first pass.